# Print spaces between every numbers that's printed in 8086 Assembly

Tags: assembly, space

I want to print a 2D array in 8086 Assembly and I am stuck in the last few steps of the assignment.

For example, I need my output to be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

instead of

```
12345
678910
```

I already have a nest loop for printing out the array but I don't know how to print spaces between the numbers. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Instead of printing a digit character, print a `' '` character the same way.  Everything is just ASCII bytes in asm (unless you write code to handle UTF-8...)

Comment: Click "edit" under your question, paste your code, save the question. We need to see your code in order to make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume you have a loop, that prints numbers 1-10

```
mov ax,1

L_again:
    push ax
    call printAX

    pop ax
    inc ax
    cmp ax,10
    jbe L_again
ret
```

then all you need is to add a "print a space" right after printing AX

```
mov ax,1

L_again:
    push ax
    call printAX
    call printSpace

    pop ax
    inc ax
    cmp ax,10
    jbe L_again
ret
```

which could look like this (e.g. for DOS). for small functions like this you could of course simply add the few instructions right into the loop itself

```
printSpace:
    mov dl, ' '
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    ret
```